# Combinig a static class and a non-static one

Tags: php, oop, class

For example consider class `X` that has some utility methods ('foo','bar') that do some operation on some property of `X`. These method are also useful for other external variable.
Some may implement `X` and `staticX` classes as below:class Foo

```
class StaticX
{

    public static function foo($p)
    {
        return $p * $p;
    }
}

class X
{
    private $p=4;

    public function foo()
    {
        return StaticX::foo($this->p);
    }
}

$x= new x;
echo $x->foo();

echo StaticX::foo(3);
```

But this approach has some maintainability issues.
Is there any better solution?

Comment: Please explain what issues you are talking about.

Comment: @BetaRide If you chane `X::foo` you have also change `StaticX::foo`

Comment: if you use php 5.4+ you could use a `trait`. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 2):

```
class X
{
    private $p;

    public function foo()
    {
        return self::doFoo($this->p);
    }

    public static function doFoo($p)
    {
        return $p * $p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is somehow better but yet you have to use two names for same task and maintain two functions.

Comment: You only maintain one function (the static function `doFoo()` because the member function `foo()` is just a wrapper on the static function.  You no longer need to make identical changes to both functions.

Answer (score 0):

I like foolishSeths answer, but what about this?

```
class X
{
    private static $p;

    public static function foo($p=null)
    {
        if ( is_null( $p ) ) {
            $p = self::$p;
        }
        return $p * $p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.4 you can make use of `traits`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

```
trait fooBehavior {
    function getFoo() { return self::foo($this->p); }
    static function foo($p) { return $p * $p; }
}

class X {
    use fooBehavior;

    private $p;

    public function __construct($p) { $this->p = $p; }
}

$x = new X(2);
echo $x->getFoo(); // echoes 4
echo $x::foo(2); // echoes 4
```

Comment: I adjusted my answer to your use case. So you see. It does apply :-)

Comment: Inserted the behavior you wanted. Just ass them in the `trait`.